# Anusthan vs vrata

Tags: scripture, rituals, spirituality, vrata

What are the differences between vrata and anusthan? I grew up hearing about vratas. Heard about anusthan and purascharana recently. By vratas can a person get spiritual development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vrata** means a *vow*; whereas **AnushThaana** means *the act of doing*. Deciding on a vrata alone will not get someone anything let alone spiritual development. But execuiting it, i.e. doing anushThaan of that vrata will get you the benefits!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well explained.